# passing String value from spring bean to java method

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I would like to pass string value "hello" from spring bean to java method

Below is my bean configuration:

```
<bean id="myProcessName" class="java.lang.String" >

<constructor-arg  value="hello"/>       

</bean>
```

Below java class with the 
method

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;

public class Process {

private String procName;

@Resource(name = "myProcessName")
public void setMyProcessName(String procName) {
    this.procName = procName;
}   

}
```

Comment: If i understand your question properly, You could easily do so by creating a bean id for the bean with value 'hello' and using its reference in method.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot autowire `primitives` and `Strings`. `Spring` does not support it.

You can simply do this

```
<bean id="myProcessId" class="beans.Process">
    <property name="procName" value="hello"></property>
</bean>


        package beans;
        public class Process {
            String procName;

            public String getProcName() {
                return procName;
            }

            public void setProcName(String procName) {
                this.procName = procName;
            }
        }


        public class App {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
            Process p = (Process) ctx.getBean("myProcessId");
            System.out.println(p.getProcName());//will print hello
        }

}
```

Comment: That's not correct. You can easily autowire Strings as in the following example, where you inject the myProcessName bean (defined above): @Value(value="#{myProcessName}")
 private String procName;

Comment: or alternatively: @Autowired @Qualifier("myProcessName")